# Python series writing issue

Tags: python, list, formatting

I have this code writing a series in a text file

```
bin = int("377731")

with open('{0}/{0}.txt'.format(bin)) as fine:
    for cc in fine and i in range(1000):
        name = cc[6:11]
        tg = open('{0}/{1}.txt'.format(bin,name), 'a')
        tg.write('{0}{1:03}'.format(cc,i))
        tg.close()
```

I wanted this code to write the output like this

```
    37773100000000
    37773100000001
    ...
```

but when i excute the code the output shows like this

```
    37773100000
    000
    37773100000
    001
    ...
```

Why the code is writing like that ?
where is the error?

Comment: what is the content of the 377731.txt file ?

Comment: Hi, @njzk2 the content is 2 lines
37773100000
37773100001
each number in a line

Comment: don't use bin as a variable name.  bin() returns the binary representation of an integer or long integer.

Comment: I'm surprised that code works at all.  `for cc in fine and i in range(1000):` probably doesn't do whatever you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate on `fine` (`for cc in fine`) what you get is the line *with* the line break, hence the linebreak between `cc` and `i`.

If you display it, you will see:

```
>>> cc
'37773100000\n'
```

You can trim the line using:

```
cc = cc.strip()
```